# Separating a for loop with two variables into two individual for loops (in c++)

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, oop

I have a basic for loop in c++ that contains two variables but only increments one of them:

```
for (int i = x, j = y; i < 20 && j < 60; i++)
    buffer[i][j] = characterChoice;
```

where `buffer` is a 2D array and `characterChoice`, `x`, and `y` are arbitrary variables;

I would like this loop to be more readable and C++ friendly, so how could I rewrite this for loop to separate it into two individual for loops while still keeping the same implementation?

Comment: Why does the loop never increment j? What that loop currently does is 1D.   It is exactly the same as `if (y<60) for(int i=x; i<20; i++) buffer[i][y] = characterChoice;`

Comment: At StackOverflow your code must be in the question and must be text. No pictures of text. Related: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: If you were going to make it 2D and increment j then `for(int i=x; i<20; i++) for(int j=y; j<60; j++) buffer[i][j] = characterChoice;`

Answer (score 0):

You are just looping over `i` so having 2 loops doesn't make any sense. You might see rarely a loop with two init sub expressions, but it's perfectly fine.

What might be improved in your code if to pull the invariants out of the loops:

```
if (y < 60)
{
    for (int i = x; i < 20; i++)
    {
        buffer[i][y] = characterChoice;
    }
}
```